# Please clarify 'experimental' regarding zfs in Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: zfs

Ubuntu 19.10 lists zfs on root as 'experimental', but is that regarding reliability, features, or both? I want to start rebuilding all of my computers and prefer to use zfs; but if it's stable/reliable, I'm content to wait until it's no longer listed as experimental.

Comment: ZFS itself is stable, but the easy ZFS options in the installer are still experimental.   Canonical have written this many times in blogs & clarifications on the usage of the term..

Comment: Please refer to [https://ubuntu.com/blog/enhancing-our-zfs-support-on-ubuntu-19-10-an-introduction](https://ubuntu.com/blog/enhancing-our-zfs-support-on-ubuntu-19-10-an-introduction) and [https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/enhancing-our-zfs-support-on-ubuntu-19-10-an-introduction/12130](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/enhancing-our-zfs-support-on-ubuntu-19-10-an-introduction/12130)